# How to display according to a specific value if no filter selection in PowerBi?

Tags: powerbi

In PowerBi,
I'd like to have a main chart that displays quantities for a single week only. Either week -1 if there is no seletion, or the selected week if a week is selected in graph2.

I succceeded, but only partially: when there is no selection, I can't to display specific week -1 data only on my mainchart.

First, I used a measure to retrieve the week selected in graph2, and to manage the case: if no selection then "-1":
[see screenshot - measure to retrieve selected week](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUlbi.png)

```
SemSelectionnée = IF(ISBLANK(SELECTEDVALUE('Requête1'[diff_week])),-1,(SELECTEDVALUE('Requête1'[diff_week])))
```

Then I defined  a second measure for maingraph that filters on the first measure (SemSelectionnée):

[see screenshot -Maingraph with his measure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCMsQ.png)

```
QuantitéSemN = CALCULATE(SUM('Requête1'[PcsConso]),FILTER('Requête1','Requête1'[diff_week] = [SemSelectionnée]))
```

Everything works when a specific week is selected, see screenshot:
([example when a week is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ig0Q1.png),

But when there is no selection it doesn't work, see screenshot:
[example when no selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO6gE.png)

Measure 'SemSelectionnée' return the correct value -1, but PowerBi doesn't want to display only week -1, as if I only selected week -1 on the graph2.

Can anyone help me find a solution?

Thank you in advance :)